# Notepad++ Find certain lines a delete them and the lines before them

Tags: notepad++

For example:

```
Important Line
Useless Line
Static Line

Important Line A
Useless Line A
Static Line

Important Line B
Useless Line B
Static Line

Important Line C
Useless Line C
Static Line
```

### How can we turn them into:

```
Important Line
Important Line A
Important Line B
Important Line C
```

Comment: Do all the lines that you want to keep start with "Important" or is there something that the text has in common? Or is it every 4th line to be kept?

Comment: No they always change, the static line is the only line that doesn't change, luckily I tested and tested till I found a solution for it: this one works
(?m)(^[^\r\n]\R+){1}Static Line[^\r\n]\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){0}

Answer (score 1):

Okay, upon digging a lil bit further. I found a solution that works.

```
(?m)(^[^\r\n]*\R+){1}Static Line[^\r\n]*\R+(^[^\r\n]*\R+){0}
```

regular expression

Comment: `{1}` is useless. `{0}` doesn't make sense.